# Php XML createElement media:content url=""

Tags: php, xml, createelement

I'm working on making a DOM XML file using Php (for JW Player)
How do I create this element:

```
<media:content url="foo.mp4" />
```

**I've tried this:**

```
$mediacontent = $dom->createElement('media:content', 'foo.mp4');
$item->appendChild($mediacontent);
```

But it only generates: `<media:content>foo.mp4</media:content>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solved it:

```
$mediacontent = $dom->createElement('media:content');
$item->appendChild($mediacontent);
$url = $dom->createAttribute('url');
$mediacontent->appendChild($url);
$urlvalue = $dom->createTextNode('../movies/Dropbox/'.$filename.'');
$url->appendChild($urlvalue);
```